# TextView duplicated and overlapping GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gridview

So I am trying to make a simple Relative layout wich contains 3 Linear Layouts with TextViews, EditText and GridViews in them, but the last TextView is duplicated and is overlapping the previous GridView.

The layout is used in a fragment which is added to an activity.
For the GridViews I am using simple Adapters which return an ImageView for each item.

Where is the extra TextView comming and why is overlapping the previous GridView?

I've attached the layout code, adapter code and a screenshot for better understanding.

**Layout code**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/categoryNameGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/categoryNameTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/categoryNameEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/categoryIconGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/categoryNameGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/categoryIconTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/icon"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/iconGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/categoryColorGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/categoryIconGroup"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/categoryColorTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/color"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/colorGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter code**:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position].getCode());
    return imageView;
}
```

**Screenshot**:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TJ-ZEESqK3ZHE3cjVTMk1zMnM/edit?usp=sharing

**UPDATE**: Solved 
*It seems the fragments createView method was called twice.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the layout_alignTop for the TextView:

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/grd_user"
.../>
     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/uname"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/grd_user"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

I think that will help ....